# Simpler way to set multiple array slots to one value in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using php, and it is pretty much the same as this C++ question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171350/simpler-way-to-set-multiple-array-slots-to-one-value)
I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do it than making a  function.

**Example code**

```
array[9] = 1;
array[5] = 1;
array[14] = 1;

array[8] = 2;
array[15] = 2;
array[23] = 2;
array[12] = 2;
```

**Edit** : by easier I mean less tedious and less lines

Comment: Notice: "easier" is undefined in question on line 1

Comment: Generally speaking, to have exactly this array, you need to code it manually. But there are some functions that may be interesting to you: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php and http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php.

Answer (score 2):

you can use PHP 5.4+ array_fill_keys()

```
$a = array_fill_keys([9,5,14], 1);
$b = array_fill_keys([8,15,23,12], 2);
```

PHP 5.2+ (thanks  jszobody)

```
$a = array_fill_keys(array(9,5,14), 1);
$b = array_fill_keys(array(8,15,23,12), 2);
```

Comment: Better answer than what I had, deleted mine. Just note that the square bracket syntax only works in PHP 5.4+. Otherwise you have to do `array_fill_keys(array(9,5,14), 1)`

Comment: quick question here: if the array $a already exists and I am just modifying the elements, will this still work?

Comment: i don´t understand the question.